# Launcher stops working when scrolling through widgets

Tags: crashes, launcher

I'm using Android 4.4.2 on a 2013 Moto X. Every time I scroll through my apps and then to my widgets, the launcher stops and gives me the message:

> Unfortunately launcher has stopped

I tried restarting the phone but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it is a launcher problem, therefore I recommend you download a different launcher. I love Nova launcher but you can download others per your preference, for example themer, Next launcher, Google now launcher, etc...